# Glide: gif animating slowly when using resourse id

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-animation, android-glide

```
Glide.with(activity)
            .asGif()
            .load(drawable) 
            .into(imageView)
```

In the above code when I use resource id `.load(R.drawable.gifSample)` then the gif is animating very slowly but when I use a drawable class `.load(ContextCompat.getDrawable(App.INSTANCE, Rdrawable.gifSample))`, then the same gif animates smoothly.

Issue is that I need to load gif using resource id only because function `.asGif()` does not work with drawable class. My purpose is to `setLoopCount(int I)` for the gif which only works when .asGif() is used.